# SQL Server - If variable is null return all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been unsuccessfully searching for ways to return all records when the variable in the where condition is null.

I have a case where the user have an optional parameter to filter by few variables(range) and i am looking for the best way to do this without affecting performance, this is how far i got:

```
DECLARE @P1 date = '2017-04-16 00:00:00.000',
@P2 nvarchar = null,
@P3 nvarchar = null

Select RefDate,Account,ShortName from JDT1

where RefDate < @P1 AND
Account between isnull(@P2,(select min(account) from JDT1))
and isnull(@P3,(select max(account) from JDT1))
```

This does not return all the values in the table + it takes more than usual to run due to both subqueries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you peruse http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is just way, way off, if you ever want it to work.  It should look more like:

```
declare @P1 datetime = '2017-04-16 00:00:00.000',
        @P2 nvarchar(255) = null,
        @P3 nvarchar(255) = null;

Select RefDate, Account, ShortName
from JDT1
where RefDate < @P1 and
      (account >= @P2 or @P2 is null) and
      (account <= @P3 or @P3 is null);
```

Notes:

- `date` does not have a time component.  If you don't want the time component, then use `@P1 date = '2017-04-16'`.
- SQL server has different default lengths for the character types depending on context.  You have declared single characters, which I doubt is what you want.
- There is no need for subqueries.
- Before focusing on performance, get the code right.

Answer (score 0):

`OR` ing your existing condition with a dummy `IS NULL` clause for the parameter should do the trick:

```
Select RefDate,Account,ShortName from JDT1
where RefDate < @P1 
AND (Account >= @P2 OR @P2 IS NULL)
AND (Account <= @P3 OR @P3 IS NULL)
```